# Calculating the thickness of an stl file

Tags: python, stl-format, trimesh

I'm a student and I came upon a project with printing 3d files. Before printing the files have to be checked - for which I am using this [trimesh](https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh).

[stl image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Oy7Z.jpg) I am trying to calculate the thickness of this 3d model  and check if it is less than 1mm at any point. If it is less than 1mm at any given point then it would be considered unprintable. Do you have any suggestions what can I use?
Thanks :).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use https://trimsh.org/trimesh.proximity.html#trimesh.proximity.max_tangent_sphere which calculates the medial axis (http://www.cad-journal.net/files/vol_13/CAD_13(2)_2016_199-207.pdf).

The radii of the spheres will be the thickness of the part at each position.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).